# Node.JS reading data from console command

Tags: node.js

I remember using something before in node.js that would allow me to run a command like

```
node appname.js text goes here
```

and then read the "text goes here" part with something like

```
console.log(console.text)
```

I can't remember what it is, and can't find it in any searches. Was this a real thing, or just me dreaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `process.argv` to console the input from command line.

If you run below command in terminal/command line:

```
node appname.js text goes here.
```

You can print the command line arguments by:

```
console.log(process.argv)
```

Output of above console will be:

```
['node',
'/home/user/path/to/appname.js',
'text',
'goes',
'here' ]
```

If you dont want first two text, you can use:

```
console.log(process.argv.slice(2))
```

Output of above console will be:

```
['text',
'goes',
'here' ]
```

Read this [link](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/) for more info.

Hope this helps you out!!!

Answer (score 2):

Well there is lot's ways/packages around for reading from arguments.

the nodejs `process` is the base of it so check [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

And also as i said lot's of packages there for parsing arguments.

[yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) is one of them, [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist) is also a populer one as far as i know.

If you don't want t use a package basicly it starts like this:

```js
// inside node file

const args = process.argv.splice(2);
console.log(args);
// we are splice'ing from 2 cause 
// process.argv[0] is your node-path
// process.argv[1] is your js file's full path
// Most of the time we are not using those so :)
```

So hope these would work for you ☺